# How to Passing IEnumerable parameter to ASP.NET web API action?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have two models:

Transaction:

```
public class Transaction
{
        public string Part { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<LotNum> LotsList { get; set; }
}
```

LotNum:

```
public class LotNum
{
        public string LOTNUM { get; set; }
        public string LOTQTY { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage ProcessTransaction(Transaction model)
{

}
```

When I am passing parameter to this action via Ajax call, the LotsList property values will always be blank:

```
var me = this,
values = me.getValues();
        values.Part = 'R001';
        values.Description = 'Sample Desc';

        values.LotsList = [{

            "LOTNUM": "L7",
            "LOTQTY": "5"
        },
        {
            "LOTNUM": "L8",
     "LOTQTY": "5"
}];

        Ext.Ajax.request({
            dataType: 'JSONP',
            url: '/Base/ProcessTransaction',
            params: values,
            method: 'POST',

            success: function (response) {

            },
            failure: function (response) {

            }
        });
```

Please let me know what I am missing and how can I get my problem resolved?
Thanks.

Comment: How is the serializer supposed to know what class to instantiate for the LotList property?  Have you tried declaring it as List<LotNum> ?

Comment: Can you try it with `jsonData: values` instead of the `params: values`?

Comment: Thanks @nemesv. It is working with jsonData: values.